# Ms FrontPage to Samsung TV SDK Editor(2.5.1)

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, frontpage

I designed my pages in `MS Frontpage` and I need them to be displayed in `Samsung TV SDK Editor(2.5.1)` for demo. Is it possible? If yes, how?

I'm new in both software's, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can transfer your HTML code to app, but there will be one big problem  - you will not be able to control navigation over the page/app. After starting an app on Tv/emulator you should put focus() on one element - for example on a button. If you want to focus a button, you should use JavaScript to provide navigation between elements and moving focus from one element to another when pressing arrows. If you don't do that, you will be unable to do anything after starting the app.

In my oppinion, it will be good to make a simple app with buttons and focus control to see how it works. Then you can insert your HTML code, add some JavaScripts and test.